# Select text from line A to line B in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i'm looking for a way to select text between two lines (A and B) in a richtextbox.
I tried something like this:

```
richTextBox1.Select
(
     richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_inizio[current_idx]),
     (
          richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_fine[current_idx]) -
          richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_inizio[current_idx]) + 1
     )
);
```

Inside parentesi_inizio and parentesi_fine i have the line number, i should select from line A (parentesi_inizio) to B (parentesi_fine).

After some tests i think the problem is this:

```
richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_fine[current_idx]) -
richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_inizio[current_idx]) + 1
```

This code works fine at first, but I noticed that after a while 'begins to show results stoner.

I did further testing and the lines are correct (ie, refer to the right spot) whereas "Select" does not select the entire portion or does it incorrectly (selecting parts that do not have to)

( I used google translate for the last part )

**EDIT:**

Imagine this text:

> Hello 
>   World || A points here (Line 1) 
>   Guys! 
>   This 
>   is  
>   a   || B points here (Line 5) 
>   line

I need to Select (not get text) this text:

> World 
>   Guys! 
>   This 
>   is  
>   a

in the richtextbox.

Example images:

Case 1:

[image]

Case 2:

[image]

Thats is what i want and what the code i posted do, but after a while the code starts to bug as i said above (at the start).

**EDIT 2:**

I changed my code to this after varocarbas reply

```
richTextBox1.Select (
richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_inizio[current_idx]),

richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(parentesi_inizio[current_idx])
+ count_length(parentesi_inizio[current_idx], parentesi_fine[current_idx]) );
```

where count_length is

```
private int count_length(int A, int B)
{
    // A => first line
    // B => last line

    int tot = 0;

    for (int i = A; i <= B; ++i)
    {
        // read the length of every line between A and B
        tot += richTextBox1.Lines[i].Length - 1;
    }

    // return it
    return tot;
}
```

but now the code not work in every case.. anyway here is a screen of a bugged case using the old code (the code posted at the start of the question)

[image: wrong]
<sub>(source: [site11.com](http://picu.site11.com/images/6a70756e35233ae74a9f0722d553cb56a865ea03.png))</sub>

it select right from the first { but not reach the last } (i do some checks here and the problem is the subtraction not the lines num.)

**EDIT 3:**

I'm ready sorry varocarbas, i think i just wasted your time.. after see my screen i noticed the problem might be the word wrap i tried to disable it and seems now works ok.. sorry for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Why not relying on the `lines[]` array directly?

```
string line2 = richTextBox1.lines[1];
```

Bear in mind that it has its own indexing, that is, to get the first character in the third line you can do:

```
int firstChar3 = richTextBox1.lines[2].Substring(0, 1);
```

To refer to the whole `richTextBox` indexing system, you can rely also on `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine`. That is:

```
int startIndexLine2 = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1); //Start index line2
int endIndexLine2 = startIndexLine2 + richTextBox1.lines[1].length - 1; //End index line2
```

-------- AFTER UPDATED QUESTION

Sorry about that, but I cannot see the code in the links you provided. But the code below should deliver the outputs you want:

```
int curStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(2); 
richTextBox1.Select(curStart, richTextBox1.Lines[2].Length);
string curText = richTextBox1.SelectedText;  -> "Guys!"

curStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(3); 
richTextBox1.Select(curStart, richTextBox1.Lines[3].Length);
curText = richTextBox1.SelectedText;  -> "This"

curStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(4); 
richTextBox1.Select(curStart, richTextBox1.Lines[4].Length);
curText = richTextBox1.SelectedText;  -> "is"
```

Comment: I already know how to get the text, but i need to select the text (really select not just get the text).. i dont know how Lines[] can be userful for me..

Comment: This is what you meant? Getting the indices in each line with respect to the global richTextBox indexing system?

Comment: see edit 2 from my question; i dont post what i changed here because is too big i think.. thanks for you help anyway. **edit:** i think i have fixed the problem

Comment: You haven't included my code. What parentesi_inizio[current_idx] mean? you should put directly richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line_number_starting_from_zero). Could you please post the code where parentesi_inizio[] is populated?

Comment: See, the idea is very easy: with GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line_number) you get the starting index of the line with respect to the richtextbox (what Select() does consider); then you have to input the length of the selection, that is, the total length of the line. Understand these ideas and adapt your code accordingly.

Comment: OK. Then you can close the question.

Comment: i'm a bit new here as registed user i dont know how to close the question; thanks anyway for your time. i'll search the button:)

Comment: ah! No, I meant award my answer as the right one. But this was before knowing that the problem was somewhere else. If you found the solution by your own and there is nothing worthy to tell you might want to delete the question; although I don't know if this is possible now after my answer got a +1.

Comment: I give to you a +1 for your time, maybe delete the question is better.. anyway i cant remove your +1 but no problem at all, Thanks for your time again. (maybe a moderator will see the question and will delete it)

Comment: Don't worry about my time. Worry about finding a right solution for your problem and making this solution (and the problem) clear to anyone else reading it. Also learn from this experience to post clearer questions which might be easier/quicker answered :)